# How can I convert this C algorithm from recursive to iterative?

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, iteration, brute-force

you are all so stupid to dislike when the question is intelligent and the person who has answered is equally intelligent

How can I convert this C function from recursive to iterative? I tried to use the `while` instead of the `if then else` and incrementing index each iteration but it doesn't work. `iterazioneTutto` is a recursive function that generates all possible strings on a charset. It's possible without using a stack, but only with a while loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "attacchi.h"
#include "hash.h"

void iterazioneTutto(char *stringa, int index, int lunghezza);
char *checksum,*hashType;

void bruteforceConThread(char digest[],char tipohash[]) {
    int lunghezzaMinima,lunghezzaMassima, i;
    char *stringa = NULL;
    checksum = malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);
    hashType = malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);
    strcpy(checksum,digest);
    strcpy(hashType,tipohash);
    printf("Inserire la lunghezza minima da testare: ");
    scanf("%d", &lunghezzaMinima);
    printf("Inserire la lunghezza massima da testare: ");
    scanf("%d", &lunghezzaMassima);
    stringa = malloc(sizeof(char)*(lunghezzaMassima+1));
    memset(stringa, 0, lunghezzaMassima + 1);
    for (i = lunghezzaMinima; i <= lunghezzaMassima; i++) {
        iterazioneTutto(stringa, 0, i);
    }
}

void iterazioneTutto(char *stringa, int index, int lunghezza) {
    char c;
    if (index < (lunghezza - 1)) {
        for (c = ' '; c <= '~'; ++c) {
            stringa[index] = c;
            iterazioneTutto(stringa, index + 1, lunghezza);
        }
    } else {
        for (c = ' '; c <= '~'; ++c) {
            stringa[index] = c;
            stringa[index+1] = '\n';
            if(strcmp(hash(stringa,hashType),checksum)==0) {
                printf("Trovato!\nhash %s %s -> %s\n", checksum, hashType, stringa);
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to implement some sort of stack here to make it non-recursive. Implementation without a stak is only possible in some cases (like pure tail recursion).

Comment: @Henry This is not pure tail recursion? The call is at the end of the if

Comment: Your code would be easier for other people to read and understand if you provided a [mre] with descriptive English names for variables and functions inside the code.

Comment: No, it is in a for loop. Only in the very last iteration it will be at the end of the function.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel The only thing to understand is the call at the end of the if, it can be chinese or russian, it doesn't matter for the answer. But I can change the language if it's a problem

Comment: @Henry Ok, so no tail recursion for sure and I have to implement a stack?

Comment: As already said, yes.

Comment: @helloworld Long variable names that does not make sense is very distractive. It's actually better with names like `x`. Furthermore, it would be good if you said what the code is supposed to do. Often it is much easier to write from scratch rather than converting.

Comment: I don't think you need to implement any sort of stack.

Comment: @klutt I wrote what the function does

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks bro, you are saving my life, how can I do it without stack?

Comment: @helloworld True. Sorry, I read another question at the same time and got them mixed up. :D

Comment: But still, you could be a bit clearer about exactly what it should do. Should it take any arguments? What do you mean by "generating"? Just printing? Make the question a bit clearer.

Comment: It should compare each generated string hash with the passed hash to crack it. But the reasoning it's ok also if you think I have to print, the important thing is that i can eliminate the recursion. The only argument that changes in the recursion is the index.

Comment: You could use the array `stringa` itself as a kind of stack. `index` would play the role of a stack pointer.

Comment: @IanAbbott how would you do that?

Comment: @Henry You can think of the `stringa` as a kind of stack if you want. What I meant by not implementing any sort of stack is that no extra O(N) storage is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an iterative version of the function. I removed the `index` parameter as it no longer has any purpose:

```
void iterazioneTutto(char *stringa, int lunghezza) {
    int i;

    stringa[lunghezza] = '\n';
    for (i = 0; i < lunghezza; i++) {
        stringa[i] = ' ';
    }
    do {
        if(strcmp(hash(stringa,hashType),checksum)==0) {
            printf("Trovato!\nhash %s %s -> %s\n", checksum, hashType, stringa);
            exit(0);
        }
        i = lunghezza;
        while (i--) {
            if (stringa[i] < '~') {
                stringa[i]++;
                break;
            }
            stringa[i] = ' ';
        }
    } while (i >= 0);
}
```

Comment: Note that I put a `'\n'` on the end of the string being hashed because the original had one there. It seems a little strange including the terminating newline in the hash calculation though.

Comment: Thanks, it's because then I remove that in another function

Comment: If it can be useful for someone, the stringa[lunghezza] = '\n' line must be under the "do{" line, i can't edit that